# How to stay logged in during development of a Blazor Web Assembly app that uses Azure AD B2C for authentication

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I am developing a Blazor Web Assembly app in Visual Studio that uses Azure AD B2C for authentication. It is all setup and working well except that developing is a chore because each time I want to launch the debugger and open the browser to review my work I am required to login in again to view pages that require authentication. This is a time consuming and annoying step that I would hope to avoid.

Ideally there would be a way to stay logged in between debug browser sessions launched from Visual Studio.

I have searched for the answer on the web with not luck yet. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

In Program.cs, set [MsalCacheOptions.CacheLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.authentication.webassembly.msal.models.msalcacheoptions.cachelocation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to "localStorage"

Example:

```
    builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
    {
        // Keeps logged in between debugging sessions
        options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";

        // Set up other options
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. In our case we did this only for local development `if (builder.HostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Local"))`

Answer (score 0):

One work around I have found is to open a second browser window to the local debugging endpoint (https://localhost:5001/ in my case). When I login to the app in this browser and then refresh the browser I will stay logged in.

So, as I work, when I am ready to review something, I launch the debugger in Visual Studio which opens a new browser window, but then I ignore that window and refresh the first window I already had open in which I was already logged in and review my work there. It is a couple extra clicks but I don't need to login again.

Comment: This means you are using instance without attached debugger. You can do the same with Start without debugging option (Ctrl+F5).

Answer (score 0):

When it happens that you do not stay logged in when you debug a web application with Visual Studio, first look at the icon of your profile (in Edge upper left corner). If it is an empty icon, sync it to your account and from that point on you should be staying logged in again. It also happened to me that for some reason the connection to my account was lost for a particular web application (the problem was really connected to the **name** of the application). Syncing my account in the browser window for debugging, solved the problem. It remains unclear, though, why the connection to my account was lost.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem with Blazor WASM Hosted with IdentityServer4 or Duende latest Identity do the following

- Create Controller in Server side project

  ```
    public DevAuthController(UserManager<Korisnik> userManager, SignInManager<Korisnik> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SignInDevUser()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("username");
        if (user != null)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);

            // Redirect to the Index page or another route of your choice
            return Redirect("/");
        }
        return NotFound("Dev user not found");
    }
  ```

go to the server project -> properties -> debug -> open debug launch profiles UI -> enter the value in URL e.g. https://localhost:7060/api/devsignin